# Rails Mechanize Join Table Loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mechanize, join

I have an app that has a Listing, Tag and Listing_Tag Model. I want to create tags and assign them in a mechanize task. At the moment I am creating the listing, looping through the tags and creating them but when I get to the assigning the tag to the listing through listing tag I get this error

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for 0:Integer
/Users/mycomp/RubymineProjects/OpportunityFinder/lib/tasks/brisbane.rake:181:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/mycomp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/nokogiri-1.8.4/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:204:in `block in each'
/Users/mycomp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/nokogiri-1.8.4/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:203:in `upto'
/Users/mycomp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/nokogiri-1.8.4/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:203:in `each'
/Users/mycomp/RubymineProjects/OpportunityFinder/lib/tasks/brisbane.rake:170:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/mycomp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@global/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/mycomp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/mycomp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

line 170 is page.search and 181 is for tag in t do

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :listing_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :listing_tags

class ListingTag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :listing
  belongs_to :tag
end

class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :listings, through: :listing_tags
end
```

in Mechanize I create a Listing & Tags.

```
page.search('a[title="view business"]').each do |link|
    mechanize.click(link)
    l = Listing.find_or_create_by(name: mechanize.page.css('article h1[itemprop="name"]').text.strip)
    t = mechanize.page.css('body main div.row.flex-page div.column.medium-3.__left-col-small article ul:nth-child(14) li').each do |tag|
      Tag.find_or_create_by(name: tag.text.strip)
    end
```

I then want to associate the listing and tag through the Listing_tag

```
for tag in t do
 ListingTag.find_or_create_by(listing_id: l.id, tag_id: tag.id)
end
```

What am I doing wrong? is the my join table set up right( i think it is cause it works in the form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to do something like:

```
ListingTag.find_or_create_by(listing_id: listing.id, tag_id: tag.id)
```

Comment: so I could do away with the l= & t= ?

Comment: doesnt it have to be done in a loop incase there are multiple tags?

Comment: Yes, you would put it in the same loop as Tag.find_or_create_by, right after it.